# Adjective capitalization of fictional species and nationalities

Tags: adjectives, capitalization

There exist a fictional nation called Elf Nation. (not a creative name but this is for a grammar experiment)

The species which inhabit this nation are called elf(singular) and elves (plural).

Would the nationality of this nation be capitalized?

For example, in the real world, we would refer to a citizen of a nation as: *American* citizen or *British* citizen or *Russian* citizen and so on. We would capitalize the nationality and not the profession. More examples: *Japanese* writer, *Chinese* professor.

What if the adjective of our nation's citizens is the same as the species name. Would we capitalize the adjective then? Example from the real world: ***h**uman* astronaut, not ***H**uman* astronaut

So, would we refer to a general of this fictional nation Elf Nation as: ***e**lf* general or ***E**lf* general?

Also, would it be ***e**lf* culture or ***E**lf* culture, seeing that we use ***h**uman* culture and not ***H**uman* culture?

I know you could just make up a separate adjective in this case and a separate adjective already exists for this species. My question is mostly about if and when can you mix nationality and species if they are fundamentally the same.

Comment: Tolkien contrasted Dwarves (along with Hobbits and Men, the mortals in his fictional-but-with-strong-connections-to-reality world) with dwarfs, as usually defined. You can check whether he ever lower-cased _elvish_.

Comment: There is a discussion on the choices Tolkien made at [Tolkien's capitalisation of races ... elf, dwarf, orc](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/176914/tolkiens-capitalisation-of-races-i-e-elf-dwarf-orc) on Scifi.SE.

Comment: I would be more interested in the usage of the **dwarf** adjective since that is the same as the species' name. Since I think Tolkien used **elvish** instead of **elf** I don't think I will gain anything from that.

Comment: You have two different things, *Elves* as the citizens of *Elf Nation* and  *elves* as the race. I don't see why you shouldn't use use capitalization or not depending on whether you're using it for the nationality or the race. (And for all you know, some dwarfs may be citizens of Elf Nation.) We use *Earth* when we're talking about the planet and *earth* when we're talking about soil, and it doesn't seem to confuse anybody.

Comment: @PeterShor In the context of my question the adjective for the **elf** race is *elf* and the citizens of the Elf Nation are *Elf* citizens. I wonder if I have to use it as a nationality or a species name. Basically as *American* general or *human* general. Since in my question both the nationality adjective and the species adjective is the same, I don't know whether to use *Elf* general or *elf* general

Comment: I'll mention that it is becoming more commonplace to capitalize race designations - the AP recently changed its style guide to capitalize Black, for example, when discussing a group in the context of shared ethnic/cultural history. You have the option to capitalize Elf the race in addition to Elf the nation, although you'd lose the context clues from the capitalization.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie I see. I will keep that in mind.

Comment: In 'The Dwarf Lords', 'Dwarf' is certainly used as an appositive noun rather than an adjective. The word 'dwarf' is a difficult one to analyse, since it  exists as an adjective also ('dwarfer forms of citrus').

Comment: That was, ultimately, the crux of my question.

Comment: @PeterShor: According to [this NGram chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=of+the+earthlings%2Cof+the+Earthlings&year_start=1940&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3), until a decade or two ago it was pretty much the toss of a coin between **earthlings** and **Earthlings**. But the capitalised version is now more than twice as common. Are our (human) writers perhaps becoming more proud of their species, as astronomers continue to gather evidence that there *might* be other intelligent life forms out there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we talk about *Earth* as a planet (part of the Earth-Moon system), we capitalize it. When we talk about *earth* meaning *soil*, we don't. The same rules should hold for *Elf/elf*.

You have two different meanings of the word here. There are *Elves* who are citizens of *Elf Nation* and there is the race of *elves*. And for all you know, there may be dwarfs who are citizens of Elf Nation, and elves who are citizens of Ruritania, so these two concepts don't cover the same set of people.

I don't see why you shouldn't use use capitalization or not depending on whether you're using it for the nationality or the race. It will make sentences like "that dwarf is an Elf" much less confusing.

So if you say somebody is an *Elf general*, you mean that he is a general in the army of Elf Nation, not that he is an elf. (Of course, this ambiguity could be resolved by using *elven* for generals who are elves.)

Comment: I see... so when referring to a position appointed by the nation that is not inherent to the *elf* species, I should capitalize, on the other hand when I'm talking about the elf as a race (for example *elf* anatomy), I should not capitalize